# Need help on running sample data analysis -

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test, survey, survey-sampling

Background: I have a survey data for a year 2019 where I received 50% response rate. I wanted to compare it with 2020 data  which has 65% response rate. Question being asked in the survey is to rate the training from 1 - 10 scale.

Research Question: Want to Compare if the rating improved from year 2019 to 2020.

Need help to understand : 1- How to choose the sample size for both the years to do the comparison?
2- How to compare the question for 2 years to see if they are statistically significant or not?

Comment: I assume different subjects are involved in 2019 and 2020. Is that true? The difference in response rates is remarkable. What are the actual numbers of respondents? (Even with as few as 100 surveys sent out each year, the difference btw 50 and 65 respondents, would be significant at 5% level.) // If these are self-selected participants, then there may be no valid way to compare satisfaction scores between the two years with a statistical test that assumes random selection of respondents. Can you provide more details on how/why data were collected and on what you hope to learn?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's helpful.